# JAXB retrieve individual elements from XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I recently created a series of objects based on an XSD using the `xjc` tool.  The issue I have is that I receive XML from a source that looks like so:

```
<foos>  
</foos>  
<foo>
</foo>
<foo_detail_1>  
</foo_detail_1>  
<foo_detail_2>  
</foo_detail_2>
```

Which is not ideal.  My question is when I go to unmarshall the XML how can I create each individual object?  That is like so:

```
Foo foo = (Foo)um.unmarshal("myXML.xml");  
Foo_Detail_1 fd = (Foo_Detail_1)um.unmarshal("myXML.xml");
```

Or is this more an exercise in utilizing XPath to populate these attributes and if so what is the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION #1 - Use JAXB with StAX**

You can parse the XML with a StAX `XMLStreamReader` then advance to the `foos` element and unmarshal the instance of `Foos`.  Then advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the `foo` element and unmarshal the instance of `Foo`, and so on.

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

**OPTION #2 - Create a Wrapper Object**

You could create a wrapper object corresponding to the root element, then unmarshal an instance of that and get the individual objects from it.

Comment: I would prefer this is done in a single pass is it possible to prevent having to traverse the full document multiple times?  FWIW the entire file will fit in memory

Comment: @Woot4Moo - The StAX parser would only traverse the document once.  Alternatively you could create a root object that holds all the individual objects.

Comment: So if I create the wrapper node I can just do `Wrapper w = (Wrapper) unmarshall(myXml.xml)`  and than play with the collection of objects?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - It wouldn't need to be a collection.  The wrapper class can have a property per element name.

Comment: Ah I see. So essentially i just unmarshall back as my wrapper and grab the individual elements from inside.  But doesn't the internal representation of the wrapper need to be a series of collections or am i missing something?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Essentially.  Repeating elements need to be represented as collections, but I don't have much of your XML representation to go on.

Comment: Indeed, just wanted to make sure that I was thinking about this correctly.  One final add on, I don't need to wrap the individual pieces inside @XmlWrapperElement tags correct?  That is I can just drop a root element around everything and JAXB will correctly populate my internal collections correct?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - The following will help with JAXB & collection properties:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html